# Docker Compose connection to Postgres works locally but not on EC2 VM

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a `docker-compose` file that builds two services. One service is the Postgres database and the second service basically runs a bash script against the Postgres database.

This setup works perfectly fine in my local environment. However, when I try to run the same on an EC2 VM, I get an `Operation timed out error` when I run the `psql` commands

The following are the contents of my files

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.17
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  api:
    container_name: test-db
    build:
      context: ./
    image: test-db
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_HOST: db
      DATABASE_PORT: 5432
      DATABASE_USER: dbcheck
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      DATABASE_NAME: dbcheck
      PGPASSWORD: postgres
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY : ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION : ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
    links:
      - db
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.7
RUN apk --update add postgresql-client python3 py-pip

RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN pip3 install --upgrade awscli

WORKDIR /src
COPY backup.sh /src

RUN cd /src
CMD /src/backup.sh
```

**backup.sh**

```
psql -h db -U postgres -c "CREATE USER dbcheck"
psql -h db -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE dbcheck"
```

Comment: DB is public for it to work locally?

Comment: How canI check that?

Comment: The `links:` option is obsolete, and in a couple of other questions I've suspected it of causing similar problems.  Does deleting the `links:` block make any difference?  (You don't need to replace it with anything.)

Comment: Nope. Removing links does not resolve it.